# In React how to pass standard html as component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to write a HOC which accept a wrapper component, but want to pass standard element for inner html like this..

```
type TextLike = string | {type,content}
const TextLikeRender = ({value,component:Wrapper})=>{
  return (
    value.type==='html'?
      <Wrapper dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value.content}}/>:
      <Wrapper>{value}</Wrapper>;
  )
}

// use like this
<TextLikeRender value={{type:'html',content:'This is <br/> Html'}} component={/* how to reference h1 element */XXXX.h1} />
```

I want to pass `h1` as component for TextLikeRender, How can I reference h1?

Comment: What is not working in your code snippet?

Comment: @johnnypeter I want to pass h1 to HOC, I don't know how

Comment: I think `TextLikeRender` should not be self closing and that component should accomodate `h1`. In `TextLikeRender` just pass it as `this.props.children`. So h1 will get wrapped by TextLikeRender. This is what you were talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you need to change in your code as is (besides the extraneous semicolon in the ternary expression). Simply pass the string `"h1"` as the value of the `component` prop.

JSX is just syntactic sugar for calling `React.createElement`. If the JSX tag starts with an upper case letter it is left as is and is passed as the first argument to `React.createElement`, otherwise if the tag name begins with a lower case letter it will be turned into a string and then passed as the first argument.

```js
function TestComponent(){
  return <div>Testing!</div>;
}
```

The above gets turned into this plain JavaScript:

```js
function TestComponent(){
  return React.createElement("div", null, "Testing!");
}
```

When the example `TestComponent` above is rendered, `React.createElement` will create a React Element that renders to a ’normal' `<div>` element.

For your component, Wherever the `<Wrapper>` JSX tag is used, `Wrapper` will be passed as the first argument to `React.createElement`. The value of `Wrapper` could be a React Component, but it could also just be a string, such as `"div"`. So all you’ve have to do is use your code like this:

```
const TextLikeRender = ({ value, component: Wrapper }) => {
  if (value.type === "html") {
    return <Wrapper dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value.content}} />;
  } else {
    return <Wrapper>{value}</Wrapper>;
  }
}

<TextLikeRender value={{type: 'html', content: 'This is <br/> Html'}} component="h1" />
```

Finally — this is irrelevant to the question, but a component like this would probably be better with `type` and `value` both being separate props, and even better would be to not have `TextLikeRender` take a `component` prop, and leave wrapping it to the code using it. And, given you can pass *any* value as a prop, it would be much better (not to mention safer and more secure) to avoid `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` completely and pass `["This is ", <br />, " Html"]` as the value instead, if that’s possible.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use `React.createElement` inside `TextLikeRender`. This way you can pass component as string.

```
export const TextLikeRender = ({ value, component:Wrapper })=> {
  return value && value.type==='html' ?
    React.createElement (Wrapper, { dangerouslySetInnerHTML: {__html: value.content} }) :
    React.createElement (Wrapper, {}, value && value.content)
}
```

Usage

```
<TextLikeRender value={{type:'html',content:'This is <br/> Html'}} component='h1' />
```

[Demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/passhtmltagasprop-7y2zl)